# Convert array of tuples to JSON in Haskell

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

Would ayone know how to convert

```
tt :: (Int, [(Int, String)])
tt = (777, [(1, "AA") , (2, "BB") , (3, "CC")])
```

to JSON similar to

```
{
"user": 777,
"data": [ 
            { "num": 1 , "typ": "AA" },
            { "num": 2 , "typ": "BB" },
            { "num": 3 , "typ": "CC" } 
        ]
}
```

using (preferably) Aeson ?

Comment: Yes, I do.  That doesn't mean I'm going to just give you a solution.  What have you attempted?

Comment: The [docs on `ToJSON`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.7.0.6/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t:ToJSON) will be helpful to you.

Comment: It would be more idiomatic(the consensus seems to be easier to maintain/reason about too) to use some datatypes rather then nested tuples.  It also looks like it would simplify the conversion to json.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Aeson`'s `toJSON` function should convert `tt` as is, but it won't give you field names. To get names create a custom datatype (and probably a datatype equivalent to (Int,String), to put names on those fields) and derive your own custom instance of `ToJSON` [as described in the docs.](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.7.0.6/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t%3aToJSON) For what you want to do you'll probably be able to get away with just `deriving Generic` and declaring an instance of `ToJSON`.

Edit: Just tried this and it works fine, but if you really need that data field to be named data you'll have to write a custom `toJSON` instance because `data` is a reserved keyword in Haskell and you can't use it as a name for anything.